# How to get a pre-populated form while updating form in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

This is my forms.

```
class CreateBooksForm(forms.ModelForm):

    languages = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'accept':'application/pdf'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = "name","languages", "about","image","file"
```

This is my view.So when I render to my update view template I get the empty form for languages and files but other are populated.

```
@login_required
def post_update(request,pk):
    update = get_object_or_404(Book,pk=pk)

    form = CreateBooksForm(request.POST or None ,request.FILES or None,instance=update)
    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            languages = form.cleaned_data['languages']
            post.save() # must be save before adding m2m
            tag_list=[Language.objects.get_or_create(name=tag)[0] for tag in post.languages.lower().split()]
            for tag in tag_list:
                a = post.language.add(tag)
            post.language.set = a      
            post.save() 
            messages.success(request,'Updated successfully!')
            update_book.delay(post.pk)
    context ={
        'form':form
    }      

    return render(request,'books/update.html',context)
```

my template.So this is simple django crispy template I have used.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
<img class="rounded-circle" src="/media/{{form.image.value}}" height="100px" width="150px">
{{ form|crispy }}

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark">Update Books</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to render each field manually to get the prepopulated field.
for example:

```
{% for field in form %}
     {% if field.languages %}
          <input type="name" id={{ field.languages.id_for_label }} value={{ field.languages.value }}/>
     {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

for more details refer [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates)

Comment: So for every field I have to ad if statement ?

Comment: Not necessary to include the if statement always.

Comment: Use if statement only to take more control of the form rendering.

Comment: I don't get any value for field.languages.. Is it because languages in not a models field?

Comment: Obviously, If it is not a model field then why would you use a ModelForm? and how is it going to get data from? It needs to be stored somewhere to fetch data while updating it next time, right?

Comment: I am doomed.Can you please write the answer. I have used the model field because all of my fields uses model. Please help me out

Comment: I've already given an answer to your question. It should work, I cannot present, you entire the code.